# What is the correct syntax for "if host is not foo, redirect to bar" in a .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This website has a ton of extra domains (**note:** these are **not subdomains**; one of them, for instance, is http://eduard.fi) that the owner (or the SEO people, rather) wants to redirect to the main domain. Instead of listing them one by one, this is what I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^masetti\.fi$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://masetti.fi/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However this creates a redirect loop. Why is that? This does not produce a server error, so for that part the syntax is correct, but it does not do what I want.

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, but made a logical mistake. Take a look at this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^masetti\.fi$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://masetti.fi/$1 [R=301]
```

An alternative would be that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^masetti\.fi$
RewriteRule ^ https://masetti.fi%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

The `RewriteCond` has been slightly altered: It is the variable `%{HTTP_HOST}` you want to check, not `%{HTTPS_HOST}`which does not exist.

PS: it is a good idea to start out with a 302 redirection and only change that to a 301 once everything works as intended. That prevents issues with client side caching.

Comment: Thanks for the 302 tip. I did not know that. I clarified my question, these are not subdomains we're talking about.

Comment: Re-read your question, my answer and indeed I realized my answer was complete nonsense regardless of whether your question was precise or not. I made un update with another slight change. Would be a bit embarrassing for both of us if that variable name is the issue here...

Comment: I see. Did you mean to say %{HTTPS_HOST} does not exist?

Comment: Yep, exactly. Sorry, on a train ride, could not test.